# ZedGraph showing range in all of the diagram

Tags: c#, diagram, zedgraph

I am using ZedGraph to show a workprocess.
For this process I also have to show the range of a temperature.
It should look kind of like this [ZedGraph example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5rPz.png)

For my application I need the range to be shown in the whole diagram even after I dragged the shown area to the left or right with the mouse wheel.
If I just change the startpoint and the width of the box it is showed outside the axis like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyKAN.png) which is not what I´m looking for.

Is there a way to show the range box always inside the border of the graph even after scrolling in the grapharea by using the mousewheel?

Answer (score 0):

Use MouseMoveEvent and ZoomEvent where you set the start of `BoxObj`'s `X` axis to `ZG.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min` and the width to `ZG.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Max - ZG.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min`.

On MouseMoveEvent you have to put this code inside `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle || (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && (ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control))` to do this only if panning is started. Return false to allow pan function to still work.